# Django--complex context or complex template?

Tags: django

I'm rather new to the Django world and am converting an existing Java/Javascript app to Django. The existing app has many complex queries and conditionals. I can solve most of those in the template, but it is starting to get ridiculous. Generally, is it better to put the database hits in the view and have a more complex context to pass to the template or simplify the context and burden the template? Or does it matter? Some quick figures--the database has 44 tables 16 of which are M2M join tables. There are four report templates--the only one I've tackled hits seven different tables. So far, I've found testing things in the template is quicker and more reliable than testing in the view class. But I'm inclined to push more of the logic back to the view and pass a more complex context to the template. Just wondering which way more experienced Django hands go....

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to make your front-end as dumb and lazy as possible. Give your template exactly what it needs to present the data computed by your view/context.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the book Two Scoops of Django:

```
Fat Models, Thin Views, Helper functions, and stupid templates
```

try moving as much things into models as you can.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Reconfiguring and simplifying the database is being considered and will likely be done--next year at the earliest(!). There are some things I can do in the mean time, like adding a few methods here and there, that should help. Right now, I'm in the "stupid template" phase!